# How to import different class based view in Django

Tags: python, django

I'm currently learning Django 1.6 and I'm working on the developpement of my own blog.

I want to do the following :

I have an application called which has two class based view :

-the post message view : a view with only a subject field and a message field

-the show message view : a view which shows all posted messages

views.py :

```
class PostMessageView(generic.TemplateView):
    template_name = 'postMessage/index.html'

class ShowMessageView(ListView):
    template_name = 'postMessage/message_list_view.html'
    model = Message

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ShowMessageView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['title'] = 'This is the show message page'
        return context
```

I want to make use of these two view in the 'main' application to display a page which contains the two view in a unique html page (I want to show all the posted messages and have to possibility to post a new message).

Is there a simple way to do that in Django ?

Regards

Comment: Can you explain what you try to do?

Comment: I have 2 class based view but I want to display both view in a unique html page. I want to take the HTML Code of the PostMessageView and append it to the ShowMessageView.

Comment: You would just add extra context to the ShowMessageView to do that.

Comment: Have you read up on mixins: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/mixins0/ (especially the dicussion on AuthorInterstForm? (Also note that the "simplest" way might be to use iframes but that way may lead to madness down the road)

Comment: Yes a simple way would be to merge the context in either de function based view of in a new class based view, or to use mixins instead of class based view. But in the future, I would like to add some extra feature which comes from other apps inside a main page (such as login, comment, share, ...) and it feels like if I use these methods, it will be a hell to call all these apps in the main view.